# g++ -D flag add definition to Object file

Tags: c++, linker, g++

Ok so I've just recently started using the -D flag in the g++ compiler to compile code in different ways.

However I've encountered a problem where using the -D flag to compile one file, I need to keep using it in subsequent files.

Eg I have 2 files:

```
sardine.hpp sardine.cpp
```

and both files have sections which are enclosed by:

```
  #ifdef PLANKTON
  #endif
```

I then compile this using:

```
g++ -c -D PLANKTON sardine.cpp -o sardine.o
```

If I then want to use link to this in another compile, for the code to work, I'll have to use the D flag again (as far as I know), eg:

```
g++ -D PLANKTON tuna.cpp sardine.o -o tuna
```

Is there a way of adding a define permanently at compile time? Such that I don't have to add a -D flag the next time it's compiled?

*sorry if I've missed something :'(*

Thanks!

Comment: Each compilation process is completely independent of every other one. When the compiler is parsing your .cpp source, it can only act on the information that particular instance has. As everyone else said, you might want to look into using make or another build system to better manage your compilation settings. You could also put `#define PLANKTON` in a shared header file that they both include, and then just have that one place to modify it between rebuilds, which would keep your command line simpler.

Comment: @notmyfriend Ahh including the definition in a common header might be the way to go. Darn was too focused on getting the -D flag to work :P, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a makefile. You can define your compile in there and set flags so you will not have to type everything out every time.

Check out this tutorial:

https://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/

Comment: I'm actually using a script to compile each time. It's a little easier than modifying a makefile each time I change the build structure (I'm still prototyping the project at the moment)

Comment: The link doesn't work on my computer. But I would recommend this tutorial: https://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/

Comment: tutorial link doesnt work